# Reposition foundation dropdown on parent div scrolling

Tags: zurb-foundation, dropdown

I have a lot of dropdowns in a table using foundation, the table shows a scrollbar for a large number of rows. Each row has a column with a dropdown link, which reveals the foundation dropdown menu. If the menu is open and user scrolls, the menu stays open in the absolute position but does not stick to the dropdown link.

This probably happens because I needed to seperate the dropdown link and the hidden dropdown menu list. They are seperated only in structure because the dropdown links are in a jquery sortable table and then the opened dropdowns were having wrong positions (edge of page, etc). So now the hidden dropdown lists somewhere outside the table since they are connected with #ID to the actual links

Is there a way to reposition the openeded dropdown menu with it's link?